# Firebase functions missing config json

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I've been away from firebase for about 2 years and just got back trying to fix couple of things in my firebase-functions. There was a plenty to update with my packages, but I got to the point where I am not sure what to do next to deploy the fixed function.

Here is the error that happens after trying to deploy a function in terminal:

```
lukasstateczny@Lukass-MacBook-Pro admin-pukinn % firebase deploy --only functions:mpiEnrollment

=== Deploying to 'pukinn2'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

Tried to lint /Users/lukasstateczny/Desktop/Pukinn/admin-pukinn/functions/src/index.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module '../config/pukinn2-1b14e9a65ea1.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/lukasstateczny/Desktop/Pukinn/admin-pukinn/functions/lib/index.js
- /Users/lukasstateczny/Desktop/Pukinn/admin-pukinn/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/runtime/loader.js
- /Users/lukasstateczny/Desktop/Pukinn/admin-pukinn/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/bin/firebase-functions.js
lukasstateczny@Lukass-MacBook-Pro admin-pukinn %
```

Now the config folder exists, but there is no file with this name. Also I'm not sure about these weird numbers after the app name, but I guess it's probably something like a cashed file. I don't know at this point how to get this file and what values should be in it.

**ANSWER: After a few helpful comments I realize I was missing serviceAccount.json file that can be found in Firebase Console -> App Settings -> Service Accounts [Tab]
I thought first firebaseConfig was enough but I was wrong.
Also couple of dependencies were outdated, so I needed to upgrade that as well, but after including the .json file the deployment was smooth as ever.**

Service account template in case you are not sure how it should look:

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "yourProjectName",
    "private_key_id": "...a89fds980asddfs890dsa...",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...ahjk8123hdjak91hjkdsa...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-0000f@yourProject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "...1234567...",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/000/firebase-adminsdk-0000%40yourproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Obviously make sure not to share real values with anyone.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the minimal code and configuration that causes the problem.  We should be able to reproduce the problem using the instructions you provide.  Also please do not show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read.

Comment: Would this be enough @DougStevenson?

Comment: A package.json for react is not helpful here because the react part isn't having problems. It's just Cloud Functions.  firebase.json is not terribly helpful in this case.  What you are missing is the configuration and code for the functions that are failing to deploy.  Ideally you can start a new project form scratch and show us what you did to it that makes it fail on deployment.

Comment: @DougStevenson. I thought first that package.json might show some packages that are outdated that I forgot to update perhaps, but yeah makes sense that it isn't much connected to this particular issue. Thanks for the help since your comment about missing config actually led me to realize that I am missing config for serviceAccount in my app xD.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing your `.firebase` folder which may contain a very old hosting cache file and retry the deployment if you are able to build the app locally just fine.

Additionally, prior to deploying those functions, I would verify in development that they are working as you intend using your `Functions Emulator`. In the React client you obviously need to use the `connectEmulator` function for development to be able to test you functions if you haven't already.

You also may want to go inside your `functions` folder, remove the `build` folder, run `npm run build` and ensure your functions are building just fine.

Comment: Thanks for this. This helped. Also I realized I was missing serviceAccount.json which was the file it tried to get. I forgot that was another file necessary for admin to communicate with firebase. I thought that firebaseConfig was enough. All works now.

Comment: Oh yes that missing JSON would be a problem! You could update your original post with the answer *bolded* so future readers with the same issue would see the solution easier.